# Call a slot from QML which requires a QImage or QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

I have a slot in my application backend which requires a QImage or QPixmap.

Now I want to call it from my QML frontend by providing a png from the resource file:

```
sessionManager.createUser("user", "qrc:///src/sessionManager/qml/Assets/user.png")
```

But if I set a breakpoint in createUser I can see that the passed image is null.

How is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this from QML. The correct way to do it would be change your C++ API/create a new one to accept a path to the image and load it there instead.